# Custom Tags doing something at the beginning and end

Tags: django, django-templates

I am writing a custom tag to create dynamic css and other html formating around container html blocks. Basically, the idea is I want some the boilerplate HTML to be nested around the "meat" of the html blocks. For example, let's say I have a table, I then want to nest some divs (or possibly other things) around that. These divs are not always the same, but generally the same.

What I want is for the closing tag, as an example, `{% endtag %}` to also do something.

The beginning of the tag seems easy enough and can be done using inclusion.

To demonstrate my idea above, here is some HTML without the tag:

```
<div class=someclass>
    <table class=someclass id=someid>
        stuff here
    </table>
</div>
```

Instead, using the tag, it would look like this:

```
{% customtag arg %}
    <table class=someclass id=someid>
        stuff here
    </table>
{% endcustomtag %}
```

In the demonstration above customtag and endcustom tag each render the appropriate portions of the div.

In short:

Is it possible to use `{% endXXX %}`, or some other mechanism, to render HTML at the end of the block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#parsing-until-another-block-tag

Have a look at a tag we've created, using the end tag:

https://github.com/pythonheads/inc/blob/master/src/inc/templatetags/inc.py#L97

Comment: Repo does not exist anymore